# Zebra printer stop each label

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, zebra-printers, bartender

**Zebra model:** Zebra Z4M

I have a problem with printing labels from a PDF file on a Zebra printer. If I send a file to be printed that has several pages (one page = one label) the printer prints one page, pauses for 2 seconds, and prints another label (instead of printing continuously)

I create C# app where I generate simple PDF file (using iTextSharp) and print it on Zebra (i send file to Zebra one file who contain multiple pages -> each page == one label)
[image]

In iTextSharp i create PDF file with custom dimension:

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(353, 180);
Document pdfDocument = new Document(pgSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

In printer i set dimensions corresponding to the actual size of the label:

[image]

***P.S.***

I noticed that if I send a PDF file for printing with only one page, but by setting the number of copies (e.g. to 5 copies) the printer prints normally (without pausing on each label)

Comment: If you have a dispenser, make sure to clean the sensor at the front middle of it. And you need to set the printer to Continuous Mode (not Peel Off), see https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/gx-gk-series-peel-option-setup-and-issues.html

Comment: With sensor is everythink ok. If I print a PDF document with only one page (one label), the printer prints without stopping.

Comment: The delay is likely due to the printer processing each pdf page for each label, whereas when printing multiple copies of one page the printer only performs the processing once.

Answer (score 1):

It reads the PDF one page at a time, after printing the first page it will clear it from memory then convert and load the second page.

This printer is discontinued, PDF is not easy to print, especially for old models.

I recommend using [ZebraDesigner Professional software](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/zebradesigner-pro.html) for better printing performance, it is more optimized for Zebra printers and have many great options (*see image below*)

[image]